# Why can two different gradle-project java files be put into same package?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am using gradle to manage a java application. It's a multi projects build. But in two different gradle projects, why is it possible to have the same package name?

In project/module A, I have a java file `Book.java` under package `com.bookstore`. In project/module B, I have a java file `Employee.java` under the same package name `com.bookstore`.

In the dependency configuration file `deps-nexus.gradle`, I didn't set any dependency between A and B. But why in `Employee.java`, can it "see" `Book.java`?

```
------------------------------------
package com.bookstore; //under module A
class Book
{
    public static int id =1;
}
-------------------------------------

package com.bookstore; // under module B
class Employee
{
    Book book = new Book(); 
}
```

why this could happen? Project/module B doesn't depends on project/module A. Isn't that Employee should not "see" Book?

Comment: Please share (the essentila parts of) your `gradle`-files.

Comment: Where do you mean can Employee can see Book? In your IDE or in your build? Is B maybe depending on C and C depending on A? There are transitive dependencies too!

Answer (score 1):

*Modules* are a feature of *Gradle*. It's just a way to organize a project and its code.

*Packages* are a feature of the Java language. It's a way to organize code and control access between classes.

So although you've organized your project into different *modules*, when you build your one project, the final output is one collection of all of those classes and, by the rules of the Java language, all the classes in the same package can "see" each other.

If you truly want these to be isolated, make more unique package names.
`com.bookstore.module1` and `com.bookstore.module2`, for example.

Hope that helps!